# c++ Initialize anonymous array in place

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

Ive been looking and havent been able to find anything about initializing an array in place.
I want to say

```
Card * c = new Card( new Event * []{ new Event(a), new Event(b) } );
```

But Im thinking this cant be done. Is that right?
I know you can say

```
int ns [] = { 1,2 };
```

But It seems like I cant initialize in place?
What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: It's concerning as to who is responsible for freeing all these objects, the `Card` object?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize it this way:

```
Card cards[] = {
    Card(),
    Card()
};
```

Or:

```
Card* cards[] = {
    new Card(),
    new Card()
};
```

The last way, you will have to free the objects later:

```
delete cards[0];
delete cards[1];
```

**But**, in general we want to do it all dynamically, either with malloc/new or using `std::vector`.

Comment: So, can you not initialize an array anywhere, but only on the right hand side of =? There will have to be a name for each Array of events, then I pass the name to the constructor, or change the constructor to take individual Event objects? Is there something like params?

Comment: humm... With C++11 you can use [variadic templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/EhvU7k9E/), or even variadic arguments, but for that you have to pass pointers and need a first argument, like the number of elements or so.